# How to get Volume App Store In App Purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store

Users ask me how they can do InAppPurchase in volume.

My app is free, so they can get it in volume with this link :
[AppStore Volume](https://volume.itunes.apple.com/fr/app/orientation-eps/id1539413275?term=eps%20orientation&ign-mpt=uo%3D4&fbclid=IwAR3jQSt9cSFGoPsQ9U0wzvS9D3T4XxuHqAhADGaMIuOYPWJ33aJ7QfGl_yQ)

But they can't get InAppPurchase for all devices... Is there a way to buy IAP in volume ?

What is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Apple :
please note that In-app purchases or subscriptions, even if they can be offered in custom apps, are not supported as standalone content that can be bought and distributed in volume using the  custom app distribution.